# a base of some topology $T$ on $Z=X\times Y$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, product-space

$(X,T_X)$ and $(Y,T_Y)$ are topological spaces. Let $Z=X\times Y$ and 
$$B_Z=\{ U\times V: U\subseteq X\ \text{open and}\ V\subseteq Y \ \text{open}\}$$.

Prove that $B_Z$ is a base for some topology $T$ on $Z$, where $T$ consists of all unions $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}W_\alpha} $ of sets $W_\alpha\in B_Z$.

We want to show every open subset is a union of a member of $B_Z$.

So, we need to show $\forall\  \text{open}\ S\subseteq Z, \exists\ U\subseteq X\ , V\subseteq Y$ ($U$ and $V$ are open) such that $S=U\times V$.
Is this correct? I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: Which topology is $S$ open for?

Comment: No! What you want to show is that the set $T$ is a topology. But we are not here to do your homework for you!

Comment: You want to show that $B_Z$ is a *basis* for a topology.  To do this, you must show (1) that every point in $Z$ is contained in a set from $B_Z$, and (2) if $B_1, B_2 \in B_Z$ and $B_1\cap B_2 \ne \emptyset$, then there is some $B_3 \in B_Z$ such that $B_3 \subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.  You then need to know how a basis generates a topology.

Comment: @XanderHenderson.  That is too weak.   For all x in B1, B2, there is some B3 with x in B3 subset B1 intersection B2.

Comment: There wre no open subsets of Z until you show that T is  topology.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Indeed.  You are correct .  This is what I get for relying on a faulty memory. ;)

Comment: A collection $B$ of subsets of a  set $Z$ is the base for a topology on $Z $ iff (1): $\cup B=Z$ (i.e. every $z\in Z$ belongs to at least one member of $B$) and (2):  Whenever $C,D \in B$ and $z\in C\cap D,$  there exists $E\in B$ with $z\in E\subset C\cap D$......A useful note:  If   $C\cap D\in B$ whenever $C,D\in B$ then $B$ is a base iff $\cup B=Z$ because in (2) we can let $E=C\cap D$.

Comment: Why are you all working so hard on this homework problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base for a topology on $X$ iff

1. $\cup \mathcal{B} = X$.
2. $\forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2: \exists B_3 \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

In that case the set of all unions of members of $\mathcal{B}$ is exactly the topology that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of (and the minimal topology that contains all members of $\mathcal{B}$).

In your case, the whole space is $Z$ and $Z= X \times  Y \in \mathcal{B}_Z$ is already in the base, so Nr 1. is trivial.

Nr 2. is easy too: $B_1 \cap B_2$ is of the form $(U \times V) \cap (U' \times V') = (U \cap U') \times (V \cap V')$, so if we have $x$ in the intersection on the left we can just take the same intersection as $B_3$ which is in $\mathcal{B}_Z$ by the equality and the fact that topologies are closed under finite intersections.

Then **by definition** a set in the product topology (i.e. the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}_Z$) is a **union** of sets of the form $U \times V$, it will not always be of that exact form (open circles in the plane e.g. or the plane minus the origin) and this is not what was asked by the question. This was just to show $\mathcal{B}_Z$ is a base for a topology and this comes down to checking the two standard conditions.